# PHP And Regex - Handling POST Variables in Single Field

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching, slack

So I'm having some issues with Regex. I need to match all occurrences of

```
--property:value --property:value ...
```

Slack `Slash Commands` use a method of `POST`ing data that requires string manipulation, as it takes all text after a command `/example --property:value --other:value` and sends it as:

```
text: --property:value --other:value
```

I'm not very formidable with Regex, but I was able to come up with the following:

```
--([^:=]+)([=]|[:])([^-]+)
```

So this way, It handles anything like

```
--property:value
--property:value with spaces
--property:value_with_underscores
--property=value
--property=value with spaces
--property=value_with_underscores
// etc etc
```

I do need to trim the value after splitting to avoid extra white space between the commands, but that's easy enough to do.

The only place this fails is with the following:

```
--property:value-with-dashes
```

Since I'm catching X instances of `([^-]+)`, it's seeing the first `-` and terminating, so I wind up with

```
--property:value // Missing `-with-dashes`, as invalid Match
```

Essentially, instead of terminating at the first `-`, I need it to terminate at the first `--` (i.e. the start of another command), but I'm not sure sure how to figure this out... I'm unsure of the terminology (negative look-ahead has come up a few times, but I'm not sure how to get that to work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex with a lookahead:

```
--([^:=]+)[:=](.*?)(?=\s+--|\z)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8elmJz/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `--`: Match literal `--`
- `([^:=]+)`: Match 1+ characters that are not `:` and `=`
- `[:=]`: Match `:` or `=`
- `(.*?)`: Match 0+ more characters (lazy match)
- `(?=\s+--|\z)`: Assert that we have 1+ whitespace followed by `--` or end of line ahead

Comment: Amazing, thanks. I was right about the look-head, but couldn't figure out how to insert it. Only change I would make is `\s+` to `\s*`, so `--a:b--c:d--e:f ...` is valid (no space between commands)